MS Teams Group Chat Listen & Fetch Messages
I am trying to figure out a mechanism (some sort of a listening mechanism) which can fetch the messages from the Teams Chat group whenever a message is send by a group member.
Tried the API Call to fetch through the message ID but that's not being helpful as it's a request response API Call.
https://teams.microsoft.com/l/message//

To receive real-time notifications for new messages in a Teams chat group you can try webhooks.
